# Memory issue in MKMapView when used in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory-management, memory-leaks

I need to load maps in UITableViewCell.I have used tableview inside UIViewController to show the maps. We can navigate to the viewcontroller as a pushviewcontroller. At first it takes the normal memory but as I pop the viewcontroller and go to this viewcontroller then memory increased by certain quantity. This process continues as long as I push and pop the viewcontroller.

[image: Memory usage]

Code in UITableViewCell:

```
class LocationCell:UITableViewCell {
 @IBOutlet weak var mkmapView: MKMapView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    mkmapView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}
```

}

Code in UIViewController

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LocationCell") as! LocationCell
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.8755786, longitude: 2.3162554)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    cell.mkmapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: it seems that there is some var is holding your ViewController from being deallocated, try to implement deinit to check if your viewController is being deallocated.

Comment: I tried to deinit the tableviewcell but it never executed. I have used tabbar in this application.When I use images or text instead of map it does not give memory problem.

Comment: Yes this is because images are much lighter than MapViews, Please try to add the deinit to the viewController itself, it must be called for the viewController that contains your table view when the view is popped up.

Comment: No it does not call deinit when I pop the viewcontroller.

Comment: Please put a print inside the deinit and try again, it must got called in order to make sure that view controller got deallocated.
Are there is any other view controller references the view controller that contains the tableView, any protocols and delegates?

Comment: Thank you man. Actually I have used a library and there was problem with it. I removed the delegate reference it works fine.